# TensorFlow no attribute 'make_template'

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

I am trying to get familiar with tensorflow and NNs. I recently crashed into this problem when I tried to use `tensorflow.make_template()`. I first noticed that there were no auto-complete option in the IDE I use, and then I just tried to call the function from the python cmd:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:09:02) 
[GCC 5.2.1 20151010] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> tf.make_template()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'make_template'
>>>
```

I installed tensorflow from sources, and the protobuf version installed is:

```
$ git submodule status 
 55ad57a235c009d0414aed1781072adda0c89137 google/protobuf (v3.0.0-alpha-4-179-g55ad57a)
```

I haven't faced any similar behaviour with other tensorflow functions so far.
Any ideas about what's the issue causing this one?

Comment: If you do print(dir(tf)) do you see anything else missing?

Comment: It seems so, yes. What I did to find out quickly is to compare the output of print(dir(tf)) with the provided API in https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/index.html
I also noticed that there is an extra version in the API page except master now, the v.0.6.0, which have some minor changes. One of them the make_template function, which is not there in 0.6.0...

Comment: @IanGoodfellow I thought that pulling the last updates from tensorflow repository will resolve the problem, but it is still there... I used the "git pull origin master" command to do that. Any ideas of what's going on?

Comment: After pulling the latest updates, have you followed the steps to reinstall TensorFlow from source (i.e. [building a PIP package and installing it](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/get_started/os_setup.html#create-pip))?

Comment: Oh, that was it! I'm not so familiar at installing git repos. Thank you very much @mrry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, this issue was due to a mismatch between the installed version of TensorFlow (0.5.0) and the downloaded source (0.6.0).

To upgrade to the latest development version of TensorFlow, follow the instructions to [install from source](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/get_started/os_setup.html#source), then [build and install the PIP package](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/get_started/os_setup.html#create-pip) based on that source.